# Fill lists in list with zeros if their length less than

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists with different sizes but I want to make them all the same length. For example, make them with length of 5 by padding with zeros if length less than 5 or cut the list if length is more than 5. For example, I have a list:

```
foo = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

```
result = [
    [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Do you have an idea of optimal and fast solution, if the list of lists is large?

Comment: What have you already tried? Even a list comprehension should be pretty fast, but if you have a need for speed, you could use something like NumPy or SciPy. What are your performance requirements?

Answer (score 5):

### List comprehension

Make a fill list and use slicing to get the appropriate lengths.

```
n = 5
fill = [0] * n
result = [sublist[:n] + fill[len(sublist):] for sublist in foo]
```

Comment: P.S. I can't speak to performance because you haven't mentioned your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for sublist in foo:
    size = len(sublist)
    result.append(sublist[:5] + [0]*(5 - size))
```

Comment: It's simpler as a list comp: `result = [sublist[:5] + [0]*(5 - len(sublist)) for sublist in foo]`. Plus it avoids the overhead of `result.append()`.

Comment: @wjandrea I know, I saw your answer.  Where do you think the upvote came from?

Answer (score 0):

To perform this optimization, i sliced additional elements beyond n = 5, and replaced with 0 those not reaching n = 5 by checking how many elements they miss.

```
def listOptimization(foo, n):
    # slicing foo to have n elements on all child elements of foo
    for i in range(len(foo)):
        foo[i] = foo[i][:n]

    # optimizing
    for i in range(len(foo)):
        # check if foo child element is less than n
        # if true, append to the list with 0 depending on how many
        # elements to reach n
        if len(foo[i])<n:
            temp = n-len(foo[i])
            for x in range(temp):
                foo[i].append(0)

    return foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [[bar[i] if i<len(bar)else 0 for i in range(5)] for bar in foo]
```

there are 5 elements in a row, so `for i in range(5)`, the exceed 5 will be discard. then assign value directly,if the length of each row is less than i, assign 0

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found a pretty fast solution for me. If you have an idea how to solve it without a for loop please post.

```
for row in foo:
    while len(row) < 5:
        row.append(0)
    else:
        row[:5]
```

Comment: This doesn't limit the length of long rows

Comment: Now it makes long rows longer? And it only adds 1 element to short rows.

Comment: Agreed, didn't notice that. You are right.

Comment: Now it still doesn't limit long rows. `while else` doesn't do what you think.